# if one applies for condition execute php

Tags: php

I am trying to have an if statement here run only one or both conditions are true. For example here's my code:

```
if ($note['title'] == $title || $note['content'] == $content) {
    echo 'failure';
} else {
    echo 'success';
    $cuser->update_note($id, $title, $content);
}
```

In my code I want it to run so if one or both conditions are true it'll say failure, however, I also want it to show that if one condition fails but another one is true I want it to echo 'success'. How do I make this?

Comment: So you have 'failure' and 'success' if one condition is false and the other is true?

Comment: Yeah but if there is a different content and the same title it'll run failure vica versa

Comment: Every way I read your conditions, they contradict each other. The easiest way to figure it out is to make a truth table. Since you have two variables, there are only four possible states: (1,1) (1,0) (0,1) (0,0).  Your first requirement says (1,0) (0,1) (1,1) are failure. This means only (0,0) can be success. But your second requirement says that (1,0) (0,1) are success. This is why your code doesn’t work; you haven’t figured out what your requirements are yet.

Comment: @TimMorton what happens if I want to have (1, 0) work for both truth and false?

Comment: Need to avoid the false dilemma if if/else. See answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obstacle you're running into is that you're making it an either/or problem.  But what you want to do is take different actions based on diverse possibilities.

Here's a general rule of thumb:  write your code so that you never use an `else` statement. They are almost never needed.

Example:

```
if($foo) {
    $outcome = 'do this';
} else {
    $outcome = 'do that';
}
print $outcome;
```

vs

```
$outcome = 'do that';
if($foo) {
    $outcome = 'do this';
}
print $outcome;
```

So in your case, if you want to update the note on certain conditions and/or print an error message for other conditions, simply do an `if` for each possible set of conditions.  Just don't try to force it into a binary decision by using an `else`.

```
$condition1 = (bool)($note['title'] == $title);
$condition2 = (bool)($note['content'] == $content);

if ($condition1 && $condition2) {
    // name your action
}

if($condition1 && !condition2) {
    // name your action
}

if(!$condition1 && $condition2) {
    // name your action
}

if(!$condition1 && !$condition2) {
    // name your action
}

if($condition1 || $condition2) {
   // this was already possible above (first 3 scenarios), but if you have a common action you could put it here.
}
```

This will force you to be specific about every possible outcome.  this won't necessarily be your final code; you'll probably realize your expectations need to be different and you'll end up refactoring.  Which is a good thing!

Answer (score 0):

Im a new and just learning php. I have a data table with search boxes with this code.

```
    $condition  =   '';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['username']) and $_REQUEST['username']!="") {
                    $condition  .=  ' AND username LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['username'].'%" ';
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['useremail']) and $_REQUEST['useremail']!=""){
        $condition  .=  ' AND useremail LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['useremail'].'%" ';
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['userphone']) and $_REQUEST['userphone']!=""){
        $condition  .=  ' AND userphone LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['userphone'].'%" ';
    }
```

What I need is to search with both username AND useremail. I have attempted everything I know and spent a few hours searching for a solution but with no success.

Comment: You need to submit a question, not add to answers here.  But fair warning before you do--   `' AND username LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['username'].'%" '` will be thrashed for not using prepared statements. Try to narrow it down to a PHP or SQL question and you'll have better results.